# Limit excerpt length within <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

Tags: php, wordpress

Forgive this noobie question, but I have searched extensively through prior answers. Is it possible to limit the length of an excerpt within `the_excerpt()`? That is, can you limit the length of output without using external PHP?

Comment: http://matthewfecher.com/webdesign/wp-quick-tip-how-to-change-the-excerpt-length/

Comment: What do you mean by "without using external PHP"?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the WordPress codex, the [`excerpt_length`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/excerpt_length) filter should be used to limit the excerpt length.

Insert the following code in your active theme's `functions.php` file.

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

While this method involves handling PHP code, there are also plugins in the WP directory that implement this out of the box.